How to use Gemini APi (for ChatBot) on C#.Net Framewrok Project
I'm planning to develop a new C# chatbot using either the Gemini API or the ChatGPT API. Do I need to pay if I use the ChatGPT API? Additionally, how can I integrate the Gemini API into my chatbot?"
"When I tried integrating the ChatGPT API, I didn't get a clear answer to my question. Can you provide guidance on these points
